# help with bash script

Tags: linux, bash

i have a homework:

The student should write a bash program named fix-permissions.sh that accepts a list of users as argument
If a user or more are given as arguments, the script should reset files permissions as follows....

"accepts a list of users as argument"
can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: somthing like:- yourscript user1 user2 user3

Answer (score 3):

That means if you input `fix-permissions.sh user1 user2 user3` on the command line, your script will process these 3 users. In your script, you go through these arguments using `$@`

eg

```
for u in "$@"
do
  echo "$u"
done
```

please see man page on [POSITIONAL PARAMETERS](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters) for more information

Comment: Actually, in that case bash permits you to omit the `in "$@"` -- it will assume that if it doesn't see `in <anything else>`.

Answer (score 0):

Positional parameters. `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$@`, etc.